# Securing a glass set of shelves to a glass wall

Tags: shelving, glass, brackets, fastening

[image]
I need to "baby-proof" this corner glass bracket by securing it to the glass walls of the balcony, at each of its 3 levels.

Since there are no holes through which to pass any rope/wire, I thought about using something double-adhesive like a suction cup. But I could not find any products that would fit, and do the job.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: 1) I agree with the answer that preventing this from toppling over will only provide a better ladder for the child to climb over the wall.   2) Why do you want to attach it at all three levels?   What exactly are you trying to prevent? 3) If you rephrase this as "everything on the balcony must be attached" which is common, and remove the child from the problem, we can focus on the solution.  Just state your wind speed .... are you in hurricane country? :)

Comment: No real good way to baby proof, but the best thing for me would be to basically hang it securely from the handrails.  That way, while it won't be on the floor, at least it can't topple over.

Comment: great points, thank you. Not particularly windy here, but I agree that it is best just removed from the scenery

Comment: @z8080, looks like a gap between the foot of the corner shelves and the glass pane.  Might not the glass pane flex out a tad, letting the foot slide down between the floor and the pane?

Comment: My brother almost replayed the beheading of Louis XVI (we are French) when he was a 4yo by bumping his head into a single pane window, broke it through and somehow the whole thing did not fall while his head was in (it did right after that). My parents put a bulletproof pane instead that stayed on for 40 years. Glass + children = problems. Also, your baby will not see the world through this tainted glass (and, believe me, every 10 minutes you can nap while they look outside and say gagagagaga is very much welcome)

Comment: At least around here I believe it's a code violation to have ordinary glass in things like the little windows in interior doors. Tempered glass shatters in relatively benign fragments. Same as in cars, the windshield has to be safety glass (sandwich) and the other windows have to be tempered. Anyway, hopefully that table uses tempered glass.

Answer (score 15):

If we let OP do the parenting and focus on attaching a tube to glass in a harsh outdoor environment:

Get a [security anchor base plate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BQ343STT) AKA "cable lock anchor".  The linked one is just an example, you can find others.   Remove and discard the included adhesive  pads.  They won't withstand heat and sunlight from behind.

Use a UV-curable glass glue to attach the anchor to the glass.  Do some research to find glue that explicitly lists long-term resistance to UV light and heat as one of its features.

Use a metal hose clamp (not plastic cable ties) to attach the pole to the anchor.

Comment: But only if you own the glass partition. Otherwise you might have a hard time removing the thing if you ever need to.

Comment: *I need to "baby-proof" this corner glass bracket*.  OP asked how to baby-proof it.  The answer is "don't do that".

Answer (score 8):

silicone.
that's how aquariums are put together, sheets of glass are joined with silicone at the edges.

You can always test it yourself:  silicone each of those three pieces of glass to the wall, and let it cure, then try to pull the shelf down yourself.  If it can hold up to a human adult, then the toddler will be okay.  If it fails the test, or when the toddler moves to college, you can use a razor-scraper to remove the silicone.

Comment: +1 This is the easiest route to go. I use a bead of silicone on toilets for the exact same reasons. Few bucks in caulk, scrapes off/comes off with thinner, requires no tools, doesn't rot or rust, is elastic, and easy to clean to boot!

Answer (score 7):

Ignoring the context and answering the question strictly as asked, consider attaching it to the ground instead of to the glass wall.  It's hard to discern materials from the photo, but the legs look metal.  If you weld a nut inside each of the legs, you can run bolts up through the wood to anchor it down.

Comment: Angle bracket on the rear leg. Screw it to the deck first then mark where you need a hole in the leg. But with the context it should be replaced with a garbage can and that thing put inside it.